# Python Simple American Football Simulator Not Running

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple football simulation for my class project. I simplified a lot of the rules and aspects of the game, so everything isn't very accurate compared to an actual football game. However, When I try running my function, only the line of code which prints the name of the QB throwing to the receiver prints. For example when I run it only, "Jared Goff throws to Brandin Cooks for 33 yards!" shows up in the display. How can I get the whole function to run/print? Not sure where I went wrong.

```
import random
rams_qb = ["Jared Goff"]
patriots_qb = ["Tom Brady"]
rams_receivers = ["Cooper Kupp", "Brandin Cooks"]
patriots_receivers = ["Julian Edelman", "Josh Gordon"]
rams_score = 0
patriots_score = 0
quarter_time = 900


def remaining_time():
    global quarter_time
    global rams_score
    global patriots_score
    if quarter_time > 0:
        if random.randint(0,100) < 50:
            return rams_possesion()
        else:
            return patriots_possesion()
    elif quarter_time == 0:
        if rams_score > patriots_score:
            print ("Rams Win!")
        else:
            print ("Patriots Win!")

def rams_possesion():
    global quarter_time
    global rams_score
    rams_ball_position = 50
    rams_downs = 1
    if rams_ball_position == rams_ball_position + 10:
        rams_downs = 1
    else:
        rams_downs += 1
    if rams_ball_position == 100:
        rams_score == rams_score + 6
        print ("RAMS TOUCHDOWN!")
        return rams_fieldgoal
    if rams_downs <= 4:
        rams_yardage_gained = random.randint(0,50)
        print ((random.choice(rams_qb)),("throws to"), 
(random.choice(rams_receivers)),("for"),(str(rams_yardage_gained)), 
("yards!"))
        rams_ball_position == rams_ball_position + rams_yardage_gained
        quarter_time -= random.randint(0,30)
    if rams_downs >= 5:
        return patriots_possesion

def rams_fieldgoal():
    global rams_score
    if random.randint(0,100) < 83:
        rams_score == rams_score + 1
        print ("RAMS SCORE FIELDGOAL!")
    else:
        print ("RAMS MISS FIELDGOAL")
        return patriots_possesion

def patriots_possesion():
    global patriots_score
    patriots_ball_position = 50
    patriots_downs = 1
    if patriots_ball_position == patriots_ball_position + 10:
        patriots_downs = 1
    else:
        patriots_downs += 1
    if patriots_ball_position == 100:
        patriots_score == patriots_score + 6
        print ("PATRIOTS TOUCHDOWN!")
        return patriots_fieldgoal
    if patriots_downs <= 4:
        patriots_yardage_gained = random.randint(0,50)
        print ((random.choice(patriots_qb)),("throws to"), 
(random.choice(patriots_receivers)),("for"),(str(patriots_yardage_gained)), 
("yards!"))
        patriots_ball_position == patriots_ball_position + 
patriots_yardage_gained
    if patriots_downs >= 5:
        return rams_possesion()

def patriots_fieldgoal():
    global patriots_score
    if random.randint(0,100) < 87:
        patriots_score == patriots_score + 1
        print ("PATRIOTS SCORE FIELDGOAL!")
    else:
        print ("PATRIOTS MISS FIELDGOAL")
        return rams_possesion()

remaining_time()
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is that your comparisons are not taking into account the fact that the values can go over the target. For example, when checking yardage, you're checking for equality to 100, but you aren't guaranteeing that the value won't go over 100. You have a similar bug with checking if the quarter_time == 0 when it should be <= 0 to make sure it triggers.

I can't tell you if changing these comparisons will fix your program, but try these changes and comment how the behavior changes.

Comment: Sorry - if the yardage thing wasn't clear, make the comparison into:
x_ball_position >= 100

Comment: Another note, because I just noticed: your downs will never reset, because x_ball_position will never equal x_ball_position + 10

Comment: Thanks! Yea i realized I was missing alot of print statements, so nothing was being printed. Wouldn't the lines "rams_yardage_gained = random.randint(0,50)
        rams_ball_position == rams_ball_position + rams_yardage_gained" make ballposition = ballposition + 10 making the downs reset?

Comment: No, the first line you're referring to will change the value of x_ball_position, but the second line will never be true.